# adding and removing elements of an array from unordered list or ordered list

Tags: javascript

I have this unordered list with random elements:

```
<ul id="uList">
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    </ul>

<p>You have selected: </p><p id="result"></p>
```

I added an Event Listener on all of the elements of unordered list.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var selected;
var arr1 = [];

Array.from(elems).forEach(v => v.addEventListener("click", onClickItems,false));
```

I created a function that toggle when I click on unordered list elements,so i can add and remove the element into/from array.

```
function onClickItems() {
    this.classList.toggle('selected');
    if (this.classList.contains('selected')){
    selected = this.innerHTML;
    arr1.push(selected);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = arr1.join("<br>");
 } else {
    lookValueArray(returenIndex());
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = arr1.join("<br>");
    }
 }
```

the adding part works perfect but when the user selected the same elements from the unordered list to remove it, it won't work. it only removes the last element has been add to the array.

so, I created these two function:
First one, to store the index of the selected element when it enters the array.

```
function returenIndex () {
    var indexx = arr1.indexOf(selected);
    return(indexx);
}
```

second one, to look for the value of the selected index from unordered list and remove it if it is equal to the selected one.

```
function lookValueArray (inde1) {
    if (arr1[inde1].value = selected) {
        arr1.splice(inde1, 1);
    } 
}
```

still the same output. it adds perfectly but it wont remove it.Moreover, it will only remove the last element was entered into the array even if I selected the second one to be removed.

BTW, I tried to use `arr1.splice(0, 0, selected)` instead of `arr1.push(selected)` ,so I can have the element entered the array in specific position but that wont work too.

Comment: In your question, you are missing the closing `}` for the function `onClickItems`. Is that a typo?

Comment: yes, sorry about that. I just fixed it.

Comment: `if (arr1[inde1].value = selected)` - should be `===`, not `=`. You're doing an assignment and the `if` condition will always be truthy because `selected` is a non-empty string at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code your `selected` variable is undefined when you first click one of your elements. You need to add a value to `selected` when you first click one of the elements so you just need to move `selected = this.innerHTML;` outside the if statement. You also do not need the if statement inside the `lookValueArray()` function, which already is wrong because you're doing an asignment instead of verifying using(`==` or `===`). See the working snippet below please:

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var selected;
var arr1 = [];
Array.from(elems).forEach(v => v.addEventListener("click", onClickItems, false));

function onClickItems() {
  selected = this.innerHTML;
  this.classList.toggle('selected');
  if (this.classList.contains('selected')) {
    //selected = this.innerHTML; //commented this line and added it above, outside the if statement
    arr1.push(selected);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = arr1.join("<br>");
  } else {
    lookValueArray(returenIndex());
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = arr1.join("<br>");

  }
}

function lookValueArray(inde1) {
    arr1.splice(inde1, 1);
}

function returenIndex() {
  var indexx = arr1.indexOf(selected);
  return (indexx);
}
```

```css
.selected {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<ul id="uList">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
<p>You have selected: </p>
<p id="result"></p>
```